# Rigorously prove that $f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B) \implies \forall |S|>0 \ f(\cup S) = \cup\{f(x) \mid x \in S\} $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that I have function $f(A)$ such that 
$$f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$$ for any sets $A$ and $B$.

I want to prove that for any non-empty finite set of sets $S$ 
$$f(\cup S) = \cup\{f(x) \mid x \in S\}$$

The idea is to use induction on $|S|$.

**Base cases:**
For $|S|=0$ it is vacuously true, since set is empty

For $|S|=1$, let $s$ be its single element. Then 
$$f(\cup S) = f(s) = \cup\{f(x) \mid x \in S\}$$

**Induction step:**
Let our statement be true for any $S$ such that $|S|=k > 1$. And we want to prove it for any $S$ such that $|S|=k+1$. The idea is to split $S$ into two sets $A$ and $B$, such that $|A|=k$, $|B|=1$ and $B = \{b\}$. And then say that 
$$
\begin{aligned}
 &f(\cup S) = \\
 &f(\cup(A\cup B)) = \\ 
 &f((\cup A) \cup (\cup B)) =\\
 &f(\cup A) \cup f(\cup B) = \\
 &(\cup\{f(x) \mid x \in A\}) \cup f(b) = \\
 &(\cup\{f(x) \mid x \in A\}) \cup (\cup\{f(x) \mid x \in B\}) = \\
 &\cup\{f(x) \mid x \in A \vee x \in B\ \} = \\
 & \cup\{f(x) \mid x \in S\}
\end{aligned}   
$$

Though the idea of the proof seems correct to me, I can't prove rigorously the following facts:

1. Given $S$, such that $|S| = k > 1$, I can always split $S$ into two non-empty sets of size $k-1$ and $1$
2. Given $S$, such that $|S| = 1$, I can always retrieve a unique element of $S$

Comment: Since the sets are non-empty, you can always choose an element $s \in S$. For $1$, $S-\{s\}$ and $\{s\}$ are the two sets, and for $2$, $s$ is the unique element.

Comment: For 2, you might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice

Comment: Do I really need axiom of choice for such a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your questions are very obvious  facts about finite cardinalities, and usually you *don't need to prove* them.

However, if you insist on a proof, you need strict definitions.

1. $|S|=n$ can be defined as 'there is a bijection $\varphi:\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}\to S$'. Then you can split $S$ as $\varphi(\{1,\dots,n-1\})$ and $\{\varphi(0)\}$.
2. Similarly, $|S|=1$ means, by definition, that there is a bijection $\varphi:\{0\} \to S$, so we can pick the unique element of $S$ as $\varphi(0)$.